# How to change the ActionBar text color in Android 5.0 Lollipop?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

How can I change the text color from the `ActionBar` in Android Lollipop to white from black ?

This is my current styling.

```
<style name="AppCustomTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- colorPrimary is used for the default action bar background -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/orange_bar</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've read more and manage to find that you need to add this tag in order to change the ActionBar default color in Android Lollipop.

```
    <!--textColorPrimary is used to change the text color of the default action bar-->
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#FFFFFF</item>
```

Answer (score 7):

Use `@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` to swap the coloring of text and many other attributes to better fit with a darker colored Action Bar.

Comment: This seems like a better solution since, for instance, just setting textColorPrimary to white will also change the text on the drop down menu, making it hard to read. Using DarkActionBar makes the text on the action bar white but keeps the text on the menu black.

Answer (score 2):

Tested it on `5.0 Lollipop` and `4.4 KitKat`

```
<style name="MyAppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

    <!-- To change action bar text color -->
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#123</item>

    <!-- This has to be here to make it work; let me know if you know why -->
    <item name="actionBarTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar</item>        

</style>
```